# unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'RegexURLPattern' and 'unicode'

Tags: python, regex, django, unicode, virtualenv

I am running `Django (1, 6, 1, 'final', 0)` on a clean `Python 2.7 Virtual Environment (virtualenv)`. Django seems to work, but when I add a regexp to my urls.py file I get an error as displayed in the title. I have checked google for answers, but all I could find were somewhat related pages which held no answer to my problem. I am fairly new to Django and Python, so I don't know what causes this error.

The stack trace displayed the following:

```
./project/urls.py in <module>
    url('^', include('page.urls', namespace='page')),
./page/urls.py in <module>
    url('^dashboard/', 'page.views.back', name='back'),
```

Here are my urls.py files:
`domain.com/project/project/urls.py`

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^', include('page.urls', namespace='page')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

and `domain.com/project/page/urls.py`

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

urlpatterns = patterns(
    url(r'^$', 'page.views.front', name='front'),
    url(r'^dashboard/', 'page.views.back', name='back'),
)
```

I have used the exact contents of these files in other Django projects so as far as I know this code works, but that would mean it has to do with the Virtual Environment installation I set up for this project and I have no idea what could be the source of the problem.

If anybody could shed some light on the subject that would be great.

**EDIT 1:**
I thought that it wouldn't be required to drop the entire stack trace since the rest of it are traces to scripts that came with django or python itself, but here it is:

```
 /var/www/domain.com/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in get_response
                resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
/var/www/domain.com/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py in resolve
            for pattern in self.url_patterns:
/var/www/domain.com/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py in url_patterns
        patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
/var/www/domain.com/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py in urlconf_module
            self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
/var/www/domain.com/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py in import_module
        __import__(name)
./project/urls.py in <module>
    url(r'^', include('page.urls', namespace='page')),
/var/www/domain.com/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py in include
        urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
/var/www/domain.com/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py in import_module
        __import__(name)
./page/urls.py in <module>
    url(r'^dashboard/', 'page.views.back', name='back'),
/var/www/domain.com/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py in patterns
            t.add_prefix(prefix)
/var/www/domain.com/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py in add_prefix
        self._callback_str = prefix + '.' + self._callback_str
```

Comment: There's really no `+` anywhere in the stack trace you've gotten with that error? That's... rather puzzling.

Comment: edited my question with the full stack trace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to provide a first argument to `patterns()`, a string prefix. You didn't, your first argument is a `url()` result:

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    url(r'^$', 'page.views.front', name='front'),
    url(r'^dashboard/', 'page.views.back', name='back'),
)
```

Add a [view prefix](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/urls/#urlpatterns-view-prefix):

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'page.views.front', name='front'),
    url(r'^dashboard/', 'page.views.back', name='back'),
)
```

Or, since all your urls are from the same module:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('page.views',
    url(r'^$', 'front', name='front'),
    url(r'^dashboard/', 'back', name='back'),
)
```

Comment: I knew it would be something I would just look past like that. This was indeed the problem.